# Can cURL encode equals (=) sign?

Tags: curl, urlencode, url-encoding

I know that cURL can do things like this:

`curl -v "http://localhost:30001/data" --data-urlencode "msg=hello world"`

...but what if my "msg" contains an equals (=) sign?

`curl -v "http://localhost:8080/data" --data-urlencode "msg=hello=&msg2=hello2=" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout`

This results in `msg=hello%3D%26msg2%3Dhello2%3D`

Is there a way cURL can encode this without resorting to Python or something (which is my current solution)? I'm hoping for a cURL-specific solution, so replacing "=" using a regex or something is less-than-ideal.

Comment: Your 2nd example gets encoded fine. It sends the data `msg=hello%3D`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis you're right! I modified my example to reflect more accurately with one that does fail. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `curl ... --data-urlencode "msg=hello=" --data-urlencode "msg2=hello2="` does what you want then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be able to...  Maybe not though...  From the curl website:

> --data-urlencode
>
> (HTTP) This posts data, similar to the other --data options with the exception that this performs URL-encoding. (Added in 7.18.0)
>
> To be CGI-compliant, the  part should begin with a name followed by a separator and a content specification. The  part can be passed to curl using one of the following syntaxes:
>
> content
>
> This will make curl URL-encode the content and pass that on. **Just be careful so that the content doesn't contain any = or @ symbols**, as that will then make the syntax match one of the other cases below!

[Source](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Depending on where you are sending it, you could send it as XML or JSON if the content contains a `=` or `@` symbol:

```
curl -v "http://localhost:30001/data" -H Content-Type:"application/xml" -d '<comments comments="30DAYCC 1ST 2ND 07 000001.00 Test notes"/>'
```

To specify that the data should be sent as POST data use the `-X` option along with `POST`

```
curl -v -X POST "http://localhost:30001/data" -H Content-Type:"application/xml" -d '<comments comments="30DAYCC 1ST 2ND 07 000001.00 Test notes"/>'
```

Other than that I think you would have to use something to encode the data beforehand.

Edit: sorry if my xml isn't valid xml.  I don't usually write out my xml, so yeah.

<strike>If you want to send it the way you have it in your example, try putting quotes around the message portion.</strike>

```
curl -v "http://localhost:30001/data" --data-urlencode "msg=\"hello=\""
```

Comment: I suppose this might work if I can guarantee that the server understands how to parse XML or JSON as POST data... Very nice bit including the part from the cURL site, I didn't know that..

Comment: @aikeru You should be able to check the server response headers to see what data they expect.  It could very well be that they expect url-encoded data, but even then, if you specify that the content-type as xml or json in the request header, the server will probably take it just fine.  At least I have had good luck doing it this way.  You can specify that the data should be used as post data as well.  I will update my answer.

Comment: The problem with your examples is that they're both invalid xml.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, that is because they are examples.. I don't usually write out my xml, so my bad.  I'll update it, lol